# Granularity of WSDL

Tags: wsdl

I'm looking for some pros and cons of creating one operation per wdsl against bundling operations in a single wdsl

Small example below:

```
  <operation name="Divide">
     <input message="y:DivideMessage"/>
     <output message="y:DivideResponseMessage"/>
  </operation>
```

instead of being divide and this were more complex operations, what are the pros/cons of having a one wsdl per operation

Comment: What do you mean with 'one operation per wsdl' and 'bundling operations'? Could you maybe provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question... But if you ask about putting all operations in a single WSDL or each in one WSDL...

I think the better is to keep all in one single WSDL if the operations are on the same endpoint, as many tool will allow you to generate a Web service client from the WSDL : using a single WSDL you can then generate a client that will be able to call all the operations. While if the operations are in separate WSDL you will have to generate several clients, one per operation which will be uncomfortable to use...

Answer (score 0):

My proposal would be to use one WSDL for one **object** (example: customerManagement) or **aspect**, which then includes several operations (for instance: CRUD=**C**reate,**R**ead,**U**pdate and **D**elete).

When thinking about WSDL-design, it's not only about the wsdl-operations. 
You should also think about choosing correct porttype- and targetNamespaces-values in your WSDL(s).

The relation between your WSDL and code-result after compilation/generation is as follows:

```
 - WSDL:targetNamespace -> Package 
 - WSDL:Porttype        -> Class
 - WSDL:Operation       -> Method
```

Answer (score 0):

**keeping all together**:
Pros: one file to synchronize, no dependencies
Cons: one BIG file, probably harder to have a clear image on what goes where

**separate files**:
Pros: smaller files, easier to maintain and extend
Cons: possibly harder to debug the cross-reference dependencies, or finding duplicate entries

**suggestion**:
WSDL files are considered similar to contracts. Therefore you should keep together a list of the 'common' sense stuff and only specialise on the ones you need in the current application only. I would suggest keeping the 'objects' in a single 'lexicon' file and some basic (common) operations in a 2nd tier file (that has pointers to include the 1st file). Then in any specialisation I would create a 3rd tier file that specifies only the operations that are unique to the current application needs, or even split the operations in multiple files.